# Custom search (wp query by custom fields)

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop, search

I'm building custom search. Actually it's just need to check custom field value. The custom field is called 'summary'. However i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong as it is not working. Maybe someone will see what i'm doing wrong?

```
$thesearch = get_search_query(); // get the string searched

$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'post',
  'paged'    => $paged,
 'posts_per_page' => 9,
 'meta_query' => array(
   array(
       'key' => 'summary',
       'value' => $thesearch,
       'compare' => 'IN'
      )
     )
  );

  $search = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: `'compare' => 'IN'` is for when `'value'` is an array. you probably want `'compare' => 'LIKE'` or `'compare' => '='`

Comment: Changed to 'LIKE', but its still not working.

Comment: is the loop outputting nothing or everything? what's the search query you're using to test and what are some example values stored in the meta field?

Comment: It outputing nothing. Meta field is paragraph text "Just one sentence like summary for the post". I'm searching for 'one' and got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem - i was using array, when i just needed to use such arguments:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'post',
  'paged'    => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 9,
  'meta_key' => 'summary',
  'meta_value' => $thesearch,
  'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
  );
```

Thanks for help guys.

Comment: This should not really make a difference, both syntaxes are correct. It is really strange that the syntax in your question don't work, yet the syntax in your answer do.

Comment: Yeah, thats a bit srange.

Comment: BTW can i somehow include post title to this query too? Can't find meta key for post title.